# Call a function with 3 parameters to run through all combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, for-loop

I have a function `multirun` that I want to run. It has 3 parameters. I want to feed it a list of numbers for each parameter, and i want it to run through all combinations.
ie: for function `multirun(a,b,c)` i have

```
a = [1,2]
b=[3,4]
c=[5,6]
```

and I want it to run all (1,3,5) , (1,3,6) (1,4,5) ,(1,4,6) (2,3,5) etc...
Below I have my actual code:

```
CO2 = [0.00007, 0.00008, 0.00009]
H2O = [0.00003, 0.000035, 0.00004]
FO2 = [-2,-1,0,1,2]


for i in CO2:
    for j in H2O:
        for k in FO2:
            multirun( WTCO2_START = [i], WTH2O_START = [j], FO2_buffer_START= [k])
```

This doesn't seem to do it. What do i have to change?

Comment: What do you mean "this doesn't seem to do it"? What happens when you try it, and how does that differ from what you expect to happen?

Comment: This should work fine, you sure that you need to pass [i],[j],[k] as parameters and not i,j,k?

Answer (score 0):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) should do exactly what you want. I think this will work for you:

```
import itertools
for i, j, k in itertools.product(CO2, H20, FO2):
    multirun(WTCO2_START = [i], WTH2O_START = [j], FO2_buffer_START= [k])
```

You may have to play around with the repeat parameter, but that should be easier to determine.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
for i in CO2:
    for j in H2O:
        for k in FO2:
            multirun(i, j, k)
```